# Maven multiple profiles: can I specify most of the dependencies profile-independent?

Tags: spring, maven

How can I specify in a Maven file very small differences in profiles? I don't want to copy a nearly identical series of dependencies for each different profile.

On a production environment a profile may be used like 'openshift'. This way the SpringBoot app runs well in an Openshift Redhat environment. For local development I need slightly different dependencies.

For example: the only 2 differences in the dependencies is marked with comment.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <-- **** Part 1: next lines only in PROFILE 'openshift' -->
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <-- till here -->
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <-- ***** Part 2: next lines only in PROFILE 'openshift' -->
       <scope>provided</scope>
       <-- till here -->
  </dependency>
```

Is there a way to mark ONLY this line different profiles?

Question 2: should I use a Default profile or can I just mark the lines specific for a specified profile?

Comment: Why do you need different dependencies via profiles? Sounds wrong...

Comment: In the Openshift environment the application is deployed to a Wildfly environment. Locally I work via Tomcat - which is a good solution for the different deployments. This works fine form me. BUT - slight differences aren't ok during development and production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal is to make a few dependencies specific for an environment. Most dependencies should be just in the maven file once.

**Yes, this is possible.**

You can specify most part in the Maven as profile-independent. AND a small part profile dependent (for a situation). The maven file below proves this.

- If you run with -P non_openshift the echo's are: (1) **** OUTSIDE PROFILE ***** and (2) **** PROFILE non_openshift **** .
- If you run with -P openshift the echo's are: (1) **** OUTSIDE PROFILE***** and (2) **** PROFILE openshift **** .

This is the maven file. I used 2 types of 'echo'-plugins, so they would not interfere with each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.deholtmans</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven_profile_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>not_openshift</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <echo>*** Profile: NOT openshift *** </echo>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <echo>*** Profile: openshift *** </echo>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>echo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <echos>
                        <echo>**** OUTSIDE PROFILE ***** </echo>
                    </echos>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```